# Java connectivity SQL

Tags: java, sql

I can connect to my database fine through java if I specify what the username and password are in my code - but I don't want to do this as it's insecure.

So what I want to do is connect to the database via a file that holds the username and password. My question is how do I do this?

Comment: read the username and password from the file and then pass to the log in method ?!

Comment: I've done this via: BufferedReader userPassIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dbproperties")); but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You could use a properties file with the Properties class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html. But I'm not sure moving the login information in a file would be more secure, it would be more configurable, but secure not sure.

Comment: Setting up the `SSL` for the connectivity, it will secure the connection and I believe it. and if you are talking about a connecting to database which is located in localhost or private network, so there is no worry about the security!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Spring, defining your JDBC `DataSource` in the configuration file.